# Data not saved in database (MVC3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a list of records, for each record I have an edit button to display the data and modify the information. When I clicked the save button the data is not saved in the database. What is the problem with my code, any help please? Here is my code for editing record

```
[HttpPost,ValidateInput(false)]
       public ActionResult EditEventDetails(int id, FormCollection collection)
       {
           var eventsdetails = _service.GeteventByID(id);
           UpdateModel(eventsdetails, "tbl_SBAem_Event");
           _eventRepository.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
```

Comment: Debugger says what? (Make sure a *change* actually *did* occur.)

Comment: there is no error that comes out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your code is *meant* to do, but you never use the `collection` parameter, which presumably includes the data you want to update. You should presumably be applying that to your model before saving the changes.

What does your current `UpdateModel` method do? You're only giving it the information you've just *fetched* from the repository. I'd expect it to take the `FormCollection` in its signature, e.g.

```
UpdateModel(eventsdetails, collection, "tbl_SBAem_Event");
```

... but I'm really just guessing, as we don't have much context. Whether that's the right place or not, it certainly looks like ignoring the incoming data is likely to be the cause.

Comment: @user335160: It's hard to say that without knowing *anything* else about your app - but if you're new to MVC, I would strongly suggest that you go through one of the many tutorials on it. They're almost all going to give an example of editing data - so go through the full tutorial (don't just concentrate on that one part) and then apply the knowledge to your app.

Comment: thanks for the advise, appreciate it! It seems that the example that I have look into is wrong? I've implemented the same as the example do

Answer (score 1):

Edit the function signature, as MVC did not binded the function.

```
EditEventDetails(FormCollection collection)
```

you can than get the Id from `FormCollection` object